# What is the probability that the distance between $a$ and $b$ is greater than $3$?

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

Points $(x,y)$ are selected at random where $0\leq x\leq3$ and $−2\leq y \leq 0$. This means that for instance, the chance $(x,y)$ belongs to the square $[1/2,2]\times[−1,0]$ equals $\frac{1.5}{6}$.

What is the probability that the distance between two such points $a $ and $b $ is greater than $3$?

My attempt:

Let $a$ be chosen arbitrarily. Then the probability that $b$ is at a distance of less than or equal to $3$ from $a$ is the same as $b$ lying within the circle of radius $3$ and centered at $a$.
From there, I can't rack my brains enough.

Comment: Your question is confusing. You refer to $a$ and $b$ as points and give real intervals in which they can be found, yet you speak of square regions of the plane in which $a$ and $b$ seem to play the role of planar coordinates. I also have no idea how you calculated your probability. So which is it, are $a$ and $b$ points on a number line or are they points in the plane? I'm fairly sure you meant the former but I don't want to answer an uncertain question; if I'm right, you should probably remove all mention of square regions and circles since they evoke a very different interpretation

Comment: Also, "at random" means you want us to consider $a$ and $b$ to be uniformly distributed, yeah?

Comment: Yes, it is $(a,b)$ instead of $a,b$.

Comment: "What is the probability that the distance between $a$ and $b$ is greater than $3$?" — this still makes it sound like $a$ and $b$ are separate points, rather than the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of a single point. So, to clarify: are we considering two points in the plane, or are we dealing solely with the separate components of a single point?

Comment: Distance between two such points.

Comment: Still confusing, especially since you use $a$,$b$ to refer to coordinates in the first part and points in your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

A graphical approach:

In the $x,y$ plane, plot the region of possible points $(x,y) = (a,b)$.
Since each of the variables $a$ and $b$ is uniformly distributed on an interval,
the region will be a rectangle and the distribution of $(a,b)$ within that region
will be uniform.

Now plot the region $|x - y| > 3$. The intersection of this region and the rectangle in the previous paragraph is the region of points $(x,y) = (a,b)$ such that $|a-b| > 3$,
that is, the distance between $a$ and $b$ is greater than $3$.

Remember that the probability distribution in the rectangle is uniform.
What is the probability that $|a-b| > 3$?

You can also use this diagram to set up the regions of integration in order to use integration to compute the probability.